# Unity3d Associate an action with a different parameter (incremented index) to a button prefab

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having a button prefab so i tried to associate  a scene object script to it , which i guess is not possible , but now i'm trying to associate a button click action to a dynamically created button in some script , here is the code snippet.

```
int index = 0 
    public IEnumerator GenerateItems()
        {

    foreach (ArrayList eat in eatArray))
    {
        Debug.Log (index);


        GameObject localItem = (GameObject)Instantiate(item, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);

        UnityEngine.Events.UnityAction action = () => {  Debug.Log(index); };
        ++index;


        localItem.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(action);
        localItem.transform.SetParent(grid.transform);
        localItem.transform.localScale = autoLocalScale;
        localItem.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;

    }
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(.1f);




    ///1. Two ways to move the scroll to first item
    scrollRect.horizontalNormalizedPosition = 0;

    //      //2. Moving the scroll bar to left
    //      //scrollBar.value = 0;

}
```

What i get the value of index is 2 and i want that when i click on the indexed button (like 2 buttons are there so i should get 0  on the first buttons click and 1 on second buttons click ) .

The item is a prefab , contains a button component that I get by get component function and add action to the button .eatArray is also an arrayList. And I instantitate the item to localItem  giving it a position and so localItem is a gameobject with component button on it .eatarray is basically used to get the count number of times the loop runs

Edit :

```
public void OnClick()
        {
         Debug.Log(index);
        }
```

I can get the correct index value when i attach the script on button prefab with the index variable in it and I increment the index in the for loop as

```
   localItem.GetComponent<GridButton> ().index = index++;
```

and now  this OnClick() function does return correct index but i can't do it this way because there are lot of functions written on other script and i don't want to duplicate code and can't use reference cause many functions are private.

Comment: so what you get when you click on the button in your script?you get the index or wrong index or fixed number or nothing or error or ..?

Comment: I get 2 that means index  value which is available at the end of loop , the first Debug.Log(index) produces 0 and 1 but that doesn't get associated with the action instead the index at end of loop gets associated with each buttons click

Comment: This post is hard to read. So the `item` gameobject has a button attached to it that will be instantiated? What is the purpose of  `localItem.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(action);` What datatype is `eatArray`?  It would be good to update question.

Comment: Ok I get what item is now after updating your question. What about `eatArray`? What datatype is it? Also, what it `localItem`? Since the button is attached to item, what are you trying to do with `localItem.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(action);`?

Comment: Localtem.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(action). Adds the above created action to the button

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is create a callback function that takes an `int` as a parameter. You can then pass in the loop index to `AddListener` function so that when the Button is clicked, it will call the callback function and pass in the index `Button` clicked. Below is code to to this.

```
public IEnumerator GenerateItems()
{

    for (int i = 0; i < eatArray.Count; i++)
    {
        Debug.Log(i);


        GameObject localItem = (GameObject)Instantiate(item, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);


        localItem.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack(i));
        localItem.transform.SetParent(grid.transform);
        localItem.transform.localScale = autoLocalScale;
        localItem.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;

    }
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(.1f);




    ///1. Two ways to move the scroll to first item
    scrollRect.horizontalNormalizedPosition = 0;

    //      //2. Moving the scroll bar to left
    //      //scrollBar.value = 0;

}

void buttonCallBack(int buttonIndex)
{
    //Button Index 0
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {

    }

    //Button Index 1
    if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {

    }
}
```

**EDIT**:

You want this with `foreach` loop. Do **NOT** use `foreach` loop with `List` or `ArrayList` in Unity, but since you want it like that, there you go.

```
public IEnumerator GenerateItems()
{
    int i = 0;
    foreach (ArrayList eat in eatArray)
    {
        Debug.Log(i);


        GameObject localItem = (GameObject)Instantiate(item, Vector3.zero, Quaternion.identity);


        localItem.GetComponent<Button>().onClick.AddListener(() => buttonCallBack(i));
        localItem.transform.SetParent(grid.transform);
        localItem.transform.localScale = autoLocalScale;
        localItem.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;

        i++;

    }
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(.1f);




    ///1. Two ways to move the scroll to first item
    scrollRect.horizontalNormalizedPosition = 0;

    //      //2. Moving the scroll bar to left
    //      //scrollBar.value = 0;

}

void buttonCallBack(int buttonIndex)
{
    //Button Index 0
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        Debug.Log("Button: " + buttonIndex + "PRESSED");
    }

    //Button Index 1
    if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {
       Debug.Log("Button: " + buttonIndex + "PRESSED");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I can't use this loop because I have to use the eat variable in foreach loop inside my loop that's why I was using the index variable

Comment: @SouravSachdeva You can use eat variable in the forloop by doing this `eatArray[i]`....I can change it to `foreach` loop but that is NOT efficient.

Comment: @SouravSachdeva If you are wondering why it is a bad idea to use `foreach` with unity then read [this](http://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/RobertZubek/20150504/242572/C_memory_and_performance_tips_for_Unity.php)

Comment: @SouravSachdeva "Agree , tried it now but to no avail" Dude what you talking about? What is not working?

Comment: I mean the answer didn't solved the problem I'm still getting 2 in buttonIndex in your code

Comment: @SouravSachdeva "still getting 2 in buttonIndex" What does that mean? Can you explain it more...What is happening?

Comment: Yes I'm still getting 2 in button index no matter which button I click , I guess I'm getting the value of buttonIndex at the end of loop

Comment: @SouravSachdeva the-same thing happens when you use solution 1? the first solution instead of the `foreach` solution?

Comment: Yes same thing  I'm using solution 1 from now instead of foreach but 2 in buttonIndex still

Comment: @SouravSachdeva I did not run your code but it should work. This is a simple code. Are you sure that `item` is a prefab?. Also please edit your original question. At the end of your current question, add **EDIT:** then paste your current new code that is not working. Do not remove your original code from your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110725/discussion-between-sourav-sachdeva-and-programmer).

Comment: No I have used different way  , giving button the script ,so each button has this script with the index and when clicked on a button , with onClick AddListener ,it passes its index to the original script

Comment: @SouravSachdeva I think that the problem is having that code in coroutine. This is a bug. If you still have the code, put it into a normal function instead of a coroutine function.

Comment: @Programmer can't get that done right now , will check that after 2 weeks .Thank you .

Comment: @Programmer No brother it still didn't worked with function.